# JQuery selecting class and one of a number of other classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I've aware that you can select ".fred.barney" to find things with class 'fred' and 'barney' and that you can use '.fred,.barney' to find things with EITHER of those classes.

I have a slightly more complex need tho - I need to find items which have a specific class and then one of a number of other classes also.

Example

```
<span class="item fred">...
<span class="item barney">...
<span class="item dave">...
```

I need to find the spans which have class 'item' (so `$(".item")`) and which have also have either 'fred' or 'barney'

Only way I can thing-of atm is to use

```
$(".item").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(".barney,.fred")) ...
})
```

Is there a way to do this within the selector to save the extra code tho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of both selectors:

```
$('.item.fred, .item.barney');
```

or use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('.item').filter('.fred, .barney');
```

or vice versa

```
$('.fred, .barney').filter('.item');
```

If `fred` and `barney` only appear *together* with `item` anyway, just use

```
$('.fred, .barney')
```

Comment: filter I didn't know about - and it gets the tick because I also need to do items with 'item' and 'barney' and 'fred' and it's easier with filter than it would be making .item.barney.fred or .item.barney,.item.fred tbh - thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this -

```
$('.item.fred,.item.barney')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some thing like this

```
$('span.item.fred.barney');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$(".item.barney, .item.fred")
```